# Homebrew failing install on macOS Catalina

Tags: installation, homebrew

Hi developers i seem to be having trouble installing homebrew on my mac devices for the past 2 days now I have been trying different solutions but nothing works everytime I get the same output

```
remote: Counting objects: 100% (127/127), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (93/93), done.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly12 MiB | 268.00 KiB/s 
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Failed during: git fetch --force origin
```

I know it may seem. annoying but please spoonfeed me the answer I'm quite new to mac

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the recommendations in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495344/how-to-fix-homebrew-error-fatal-early-eof ?

Comment: Yes James I have it seems to be outdated as its no longer written in ruby but rather bash.